# Mathematica: Rotating one point around another

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wonder if it's possible to rotate one point around other existing point in Mathematica. I've tried to do something like this:

```
one = Graphics[Point[{1, 1}]];
two = Graphics[Point[{2, 2}]];
two = Rotate[{two}, 60 Degree, {one}]
```

But it doesn't work. Is it even possible to do? 
Thanks!

Comment: Replace `one` with `{1,1}` and `two` with `{2,2}`. There's also a dedicated [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) where you'll probably get better response time than on SO.

Comment: be aware `Graphics` auto scales its plot range, so a  single `Point` will look the same no matter how you translate or rotate it.  Second the suggestion to go to mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
one = {1, 1};
two = {2, 2};
Graphics[{Point@one, Point@two, Rotate[Point@two, 60 Degree, one]}]
```